# Unable to establish Connection on the proceeding request

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-time

I have been running my JMeter script with the following setup
Users: 100
Loop Controller: 5
I used Loop Controller on the http request where transactions are needed to iterate.

My question is, there is a particular request which is searching where after 5 successful search the proceeding searches displayed “Customer API. Unable to establish connection”

Please see image below:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hKpa.png) First Image displays lower load time while second image displays higher load time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you discovered a [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) in your application or at least it is not properly configured for high loads. Almost a minute response time for transfering 600 kilobytes is not something I would expect from a well-behaved application.

The error message you're getting is very specific so I would recommend checking your application logs as the very first step. The remaining steps would be inspecting application and middleware configuration and ensuring that it's [properly set up for high performance](https://apiumhub.com/tech-blog-barcelona/web-performance-optimization-techniques/) and it has [enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, Disk](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test), etc.

Comment: Hi what is the required setup for such high performance? I'm planning on running up to 1000 users to get 22000 transactions